# Python Пытаюсь конвертировать string в int

Tags: python

**Пытаюсь конвертировать String в Int:**

```
self.CoinsValue = 0
coinsfile2 = open('CoinsCounter.txt', 'r')
self.CoinsValue = int(x=coinsfile2.read(12))
coinsfile2.close()
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\KillAndWatchOut\Engine.py", line 519, in <module>
    Window = Window()
  File "C:\Python27\KillAndWatchOut\Engine.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.CoinsValue = int(x=str(coinsfile2.read(12)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**Что делать?**

Comment: Как минимум посмотреть что вы там читаете, у вас там может строка `some_text` находится, а вы в число это преобразовать пытаетесь

Comment: к слову: не смотря на то, что `int()` допускает использовать имя для первого параметра, то есть `int(x='1')` работает, его (имя) лучше не использовать (`int('1')` также читаемо как и `int(x='1')`) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по тексту ошибки, в файле ничего нет. Проверьте его содержимое:

```
self.CoinsValue = 0
coinsfile2 = open('CoinsCounter.txt', 'r')
coins_str = coinsfile2.read(12)
print(coins_str)
self.CoinsValue = int(coins_str)
coinsfile2.close()
```

Если `print` ничего не выведет - дело в файле. Возможно, вы открыли его с помощью `write mode`, но не сохранили его предыдущее содержимое.